# Calling a method that have return value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm new to python and came into this piece of code. From my previous programming knowledge, I'm assuming this method should return something(`results`). But why do some statements like `self.children[0].query(rect, results)` don't assign the return value to any variable while recursively calling the method?

```
def query(self, rect, results=None):

    if results is None:
        rect = normalize_rect(rect)
        results = set()

    if len(self.children) > 0:
        if rect[0] <= self.center[0]:
            if rect[1] <= self.center[1]:
                self.children[0].query(rect, results)
            if rect[3] > self.center[1]:
                self.children[1].query(rect, results)
        if rect[2] > self.center[0]:
            if rect[1] <= self.center[1]:
                self.children[2].query(rect, results)
            if rect[3] > self.center[1]:
                self.children[3].query(rect, results)

    for node in self.nodes:
        if (node.rect[2] > rect[0] and node.rect[0] <= rect[2] and
                node.rect[3] > rect[1] and node.rect[1] <= rect[3]):
            results.add(node.item)

    return results
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the `query` function does return `results`, but it also *modifies* `results` on this line:

```
results.add(node.item)
```

A parameter used in this was is sometimes described as an "output parameter".

`query` is not a pure function. In those places where `query` is called without using its return value, `query` is being called for its side effects.